# How do I convert a floating point literal to exponent and mantissa?

Tags: floating-point

Lets suppose I have a string containing a floating point number (e.g: "3.14159265358979") and I want to convert it into a floating point number.
How would I go about calculating the exponent and mantissa to get the corresponding floating point representation?

How would I find a fitting exponent for the number I'm trying to convert? How would I calculate the corresponding mantissa value to represent the float?

PS: I want to write some code for arbitrary-precision float calculations.

Comment: Actually, that is the subject of many articles, i.e. how to do this right, especially for cases like 1.345e300 or 2.7e-200. One nice explanation on one way to do it can be found here: https://www.exploringbinary.com/how-glibc-strtod-works/ . The site has other explanations for other ways too.

Comment: As you can see, that code requires big integers (arbitrary precision integers). Other methods (e.g. David Gay's de-facto standard implementation *strtod*) require big integers too. But also big decimals, big floats or big rationals all use big integers, so you should perhaps start by implementing big integers. Once you have those, it gets a lot easier. Or use an existing package, like [GNU's GMP](https://gmplib.org/). You will have a very hard time writing a library that is better than that.

Comment: If the number is greater than two, divide it by two until it is in [1, 2). (That is the interval from 1 to 2 that includes 1 but not 2.) The number of times you divided will be the exponent. If the number is less than one, multiply it by two until it is in [1, 2). The exponent will be the negative of the number of times you multiplied. If the number is already in [1, 2), the exponent is zero. Convert the number in [1, 2) that you ended up with to binary. Round it to however many bits fit in your significand. The result is the significand. Except you may want to separate the sign.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If you post that as an answer I can accept it as the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remember the sign (+ or −) and change the number to its absolute value.

Normalize the significand to be in [1, 2) and calculate the exponent:

- If the number is greater than two, divide it by two until it is in [1, 2). (That is the interval from 1 to 2 that includes 1 but not 2.) The number of times you divided will be the exponent.
- If the number is less than one, multiply it by two until it is in [1, 2). The exponent will be the negative of the number of times you multiplied.
- If the number is already in [1, 2), the exponent is zero. Convert the number in [1, 2) that you ended up with to binary.

Then round the number to fit in the significand of the floating-point format:

- Round the number to as many bits as the significand allows. If this pushes the number up to two, divide it by two and add one to the exponent.

Now you have the sign, the exponent, and the significand.